# php strpos() difference between returning 0 and false?

Tags: php, strpos

```
if(strpos("http://www.example.com","http://www.")==0){ // do work}
```

I'd expect this to resolve as true, which it does.  But what happens when I do

```
if(strpos("abcdefghijklmnop","http://www.")==0){// do work}
```

This also passes on php 5 because as far as I can work out the strpos returns false which translates as 0.

Is this correct thinking/behaviour?  If so what is the workaround for testing for that a substring is at the beginning of another string?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Yes, this is correct / expected behavior :

- `strpos` can return `0` when there is a match at the beginning of the string
- and it will return `false` when there is no match

The thing is you should not use `==` to compare `0` and `false` ; you should use `===`, like this :

```
if(strpos("abcdefghijklmnop","http://www.") === 0) {

}
```

Or :

```
if(strpos("abcdefghijklmnop","http://www.") === false) {

}
```

For more informations, see [Comparison Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) :

- `$a == $b` will be `TRUE` if `$a` is equal to `$b`.
- `$a === $b` will be `TRUE` if `$a` is equal to `$b`, and **they are of the same type**.

And, quoting [the manual page of `strpos`](http://www.php.net/strpos) :

> This function may return Boolean
>   `FALSE`, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to
>   `FALSE`, such as `0` or `""`.  
> Please
>   read the section on [Booleans](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) for
>   more information. 
> Use [the `===`
>   operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for testing the return
>   value of this function.

Answer (score 14):

`===` and `!==` compare type *and* value as shown below:

```
if (strpos("abcdefghijklmnop", "http://www.") !== false) {
     // do work     
}
```

Comment: for strpos() this answer is the best

Answer (score 5):

strpos returns an int or boolean false. the == operator also evaluates 0 to mean false, you want to use the === operator (three equals signs) that also checks that the types being compared are the same instead of just seeing if they can be evaluated to mean the same.

so

```
if (strpos($hastack, $needle) === 0)
{
    // the $needle is found at position 0 in the $haystack
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`0` is a possible return value from `strpos` when it finds a match at the very beginning. In case if the match is not found it returns `false`(boolean). So you need to check the return value of `strpos` using the `===` operator which check the value and the type rather than using `==` which just checks value.

Answer (score -2):

I personally tend to use this way :

```
if(!strpos($v,'ttp:'))$v='http://'.$v;
```

or

```
if(strpos(' '.$v,'http'))
```

to avoid the "`0`" position then always make it a number more than `0`
cheers

Comment: If your code uses non-standard ways in non-standard notation to fix standard problems all maintainability has left the building. Every decent PHP developer knows and expects `===` notation - your answer just presents an obsolete performance and readability killer.

Comment: I consider this pseudo code at best. Readers, consider the appropriate return types on this built in function.