# strpos issue with 0==false?

Tags: php

I'm using strpos to find the position of a string in another string. I first check if the string is found at all in there. Here's my line:

```
if (strpos($grafik['data'],$ss1)<>false && strpos($grafik['data'],$ss2)<>false && strpos($grafik['data'],$ss1) < strpos($grafik['data'],$ss2))
```

I check if both strings are contained and then I want the first one to be placed before the second one. In the php manual it says that strpos returns false when string is not found. However if my string starts at the zero position (strpos returns 0 since its the beginning), it seems like this statement

```
strpos($grafik['data'],$ss1)<>false
```

is false. Somehow 0==false ? How do I make the statement true when strpos returns 0 ?

Comment: See [php 5 strpos() difference between returning 0 and false?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396713/php-5-strpos-difference-between-returning-0-and-false).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php:

> Warning
>
> This function may return Boolean
>   FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to
>   FALSE, such as 0 or "". Please read
>   the section on [Booleans](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) for more
>   information. Use [the === operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for
>   testing the return value of this
>   function.

You have to use the `===` operator instead of `==`.

In your case, instead of using `<>`, use `!==`:

```
strpos($grafik['data'], $ss1) !== false
```

This will return TRUE if `$ss1` is found in `$grafik['data']`

Comment: hehe.. beaten by few seconds ;-).. +1

Comment: Only about 120 seconds (+- 60 seconds) :p

Answer (score 5):

You need to check with ===. This will make sure you have exact false and not 0.

Answer (score 4):

This function behaves unpredictably, so to be sure it'll have deterministic behavior use either

```
if(strpos($text,$string)===false)
```

or test it using a variable

`$pos=strpos($text,$string);
if($pos===false)`

Comment: $pos here can still have a truthy or falsy value, so you should follow your own advice and use ===false instead of ! here, too. :)