# am I using strpos correctly? Not getting the results

Tags: php, string, if-statement, strpos

I've got a php while loop going (creating a search script), and I'm looking to match up values to see which items should go into the search results. strpos seems to work just fine until all of a sudden when it refuses to work correctly on this particular spot...

```
if (strpos('a', 'a')) {
 continue;
}
```

Shouldn't that NOT reach continue? "a" does contains "a" after all, but in my script it's reaching the continue.

Comment: Could you show the surrounding code as this does as its intended to, and doesnt run the 'continue'.. so we'll need to see the surrounding.

Comment: It returns [the position](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4192039/3110638), which is `0`=`false`. Just use `if(strpos('a', 'a') !== false)`

Answer (score 1):

All is ok, just try this codes:

```
<?php

$value = strpos('qa', 'a');
var_dump($value);

if($value) {
 echo "inside\n<br>";
}
```

Output:

> int(1)
>
> inside

```
<?php
$value = strpos('aq', 'a');
var_dump($value);

if($value) {
 echo "inside\n<br>";
}
```

Output:

> int(0)

In the second code `$value` is evaluate as `false (boolean)` in the typecast, because the position of `a` is `0` and when you evaluate `0` inside the `if()` the value is casting to `false`.

You should use this code:

```
if(strpos('a', 'a') === 0) {
 echo "inside\n<br>";
}
```

Output:

> inside

You can read more at:

> http://php.net/strpos
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php